# Join with select SQL query?

Tags: sql, join

I'm trying to run a query on a table (the one Wordpress uses) where I want to select the ID and post_type columns from one table, then do a Left Join to another table, two separate times (getting separate data).

This is what I have so far, but it's not cutting the mustard:

```
SELECT derby_posts.id        AS pID, 
       derby_posts.post_type AS tier 
FROM   derby_posts 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT derby_postmeta.post_id  AS dbID1, 
                         derby_postmeta.meta_key AS dbMeta1) 
              ON pid = dbid1 
                 AND dbmeta1 = 'twitter' 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT derby_postmeta.post_id  AS dbID2, 
                         derby_postmeta.meta_key AS dbMeta2) 
              ON pid = dbid2 
                 AND dbmeta2 = 'website' 
WHERE  tier IN ('local', 'regional', 'national')
```

I'm sure I'm missing something super simple...

Edit: here's the solution that worked for me. Table alias helped, putting all my SELECT statements together cleaned things up. Also, I realized I could remove items from the SELECT, even though I'm using them in the Join, which cleans up the results a lot.

```
SELECT 
    db.ID as id, 
    db.post_type as tier,
    dpm1.meta_value as twitter,
    dpm2.meta_value as website
FROM derby_posts db
LEFT JOIN derby_postmeta dpm1 ON (db.ID = dpm1.post_id AND dpm1.meta_key = 'twitter' )
LEFT JOIN derby_postmeta dpm2 ON (db.ID = dpm2.post_id AND dpm2.meta_key = 'website' )
WHERE db.post_type IN ('local','regional','national')
```

Comment: I've edited your question for formatting and changed your filter to use `IN` instead of multiple `OR` statements.

Comment: "this isn't working either" is not an error message. How is not working? Does it return 0 rows, does it return wrong results, does it show error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I 'm sure I'm missing something super simple...

You are right!

You need to give your `select`s an alias, and use that alias in the `ON` clause. You are also missing a `FROM <table>` - a required part of a `SELECT` statement that reads from a table:

```
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT derby_postmeta.post_id  AS dbID1, 
           derby_postmeta.meta_key AS dbMeta1
    FROM someTable
) dpm ON pid = dpm.dbid1 AND dpm.dbmeta1 = 'twitter'
```

I gave the results of your `SELECT` an alias `dpm`, and used it to "link up" the rows from the inner select to the rows of your outer select.

Comment: Hmm... when I do that, it doesn't recognize the aliases for the original table called (see edited question).

Comment: @BenjaminAllison Depending on your RDBMS, you may need to give the original table an alias as well.

Comment: I've added an alias, but still getting the same error. Posted edit (fwiw, this is MYSQL on MAMP).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    db.derby_posts.ID as pID, 
    db.derby_posts.post_type as tier,
    dpm1.post_id as dbID1,
    dpm1.meta_key as dbMeta1,
    dpm2.post_id as dbID2,
    dpm2.meta_key as dbMeta2
FROM derby_posts db
LEFT JOIN derby_postmeta dpm1 ON (db.pID = dpm1.post_id AND dpm1.meta_key= 'twitter')
LEFT JOIN derby_postmeta dpm2 ON (db.pID = dbm2.post_id AND dbm2.meta_key = 'website')
WHERE tier IN ('local','regional','national')
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this is really confusing... where did dpm1 and dpm2 come from? The two tables I'm joining are derby_posts, and derby_postmeta, and they're both part of the same database. Also, derby_postmeta is one table that I'm trying to join twice.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN derby_postmeta dpm1` Joins derby_postmeta as a table named dpm1. That way you can put all your selects in one spot and refer to the correct tables. So if you join them both I usually call one `table1` and the other `table2` then I can still call everything in my main select statement and see which tables I am grabbing what fields from. Rather than dig through my Joins.